# How to Use conditional match in neo4j

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, neo4j

I am pretty new to Neo4j.
I have A node Person having a property `hasSecondaryAddress` and Person has the primary address and secondary address.
Now I want to return address from address based on `hasSecondaryAddress`

Condition: if `hasSecondaryAddress` is true then it should return `SecondaryAddress` and if `hasSecondaryAddress` is false then it should return `PrimaryAddress`.

NOTE: currently I have to use  union to return the data

Comment: Maybe you can share the code you've already tried? So that people don't post duplicates to your current solution.

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier to use [coalesce()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce) for this, which returns the first non-null value from the given parameters. This way you don't even need `hasSecondaryAddress`.

```
MATCH (p:Person)
RETURN coalesce(p.SecondaryAddress, p.PrimaryAddress) as address
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [case](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#syntax-simple-case) operation in neo4j to do:

```
MATCH(p:Person) RETURN
CASE p.hasSecondaryAddress
 WHEN true THEN p.SecondaryAddress
 ELSE p.PrimaryAddress
END
```